# install cakephp in subdirectory of another cake app

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

How to install app in a subdirectory of another app?

For example, if it is the main app folder structure:

```
/app/Config
/app/Controller
/app/Model
/app/webroot
...
```

I want to put the second app files in a directory named 'client', so new structure should be:

```
/app/Config
/app/Controller
/app/Model
/app/webroot
/app/client/Model
/app/client/webroot
...
```

and if first app url is `http://example.com`, the second one should be `http://example.com/client`

I tried putting some files in `client` folder, but cake thinks its one of its controllers and try to find its action. (so 404 error occurred)

Comment: If you have access to server configuration then simply define both URL in web server, e.g. apache, configuration along with the path of the files. Then you can put the files for both apps anywhere on the server without having to nesting the project directories.

Comment: If you really want to do this (IMO, @Shishir method is better), you need to modify redirect rules in your `.htaccess` (at least the one in your root or the one in `app`) to redirect to `/app/client` instead of `/app/webroot/index.php` when necessary.

Comment: have you tried putting your second application in the webroot directory of the first one ? so it will be `/app/webroot/client/your_files` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem in your default CakePHP installation.

You can use a 'client' prefix and in the your default controller you can add the method 'client_index'

Look here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing